# @font-face declaration doesn't follow the fontspring bulletproof syntax

Tags: html, css, atom-editor, csslint

I have been trying this code in CSS but it is giving me this error.

[image: The Error:-]

The Code is this:

[image: Code:-]

Directory:-

[image: Directory:-]

I can't figure it out how to solve this. Also it hasn't run in my webpage browser.
I have used Chrome as well as Microsoft Edge but not run in both.

Comment: font `url` wrong try this way `src :url('../bebasNeue-Regulat.ttf')`

Answer (score 0):

The problem here was the font URL in the font-face. Replace line 3 with the below line.

```
src :url('../bebasNeue-Regulat.ttf')
```